# e4 databinding converter exception not catch

Tags: data-binding, eclipse-rcp, jface, e4

I have created a custom converter to convert a String back into a Date.

```
public Object convert(Object fromObject){
   if (fromObject != null && fromObject.toString().trim().length() == 0){
       return null;
   }

   for (DateFormat f : formats){
       try{
            return f.parse(fromObject.toString());
       }catch (ParseException e){
           // Ignore
       }
   }

   throw new RuntimeException(message);
}
```

Basically, if the string is not parsable a RuntimeException will be thrown.

I have added the converter to the update strategy in the data-dinding and it is being called.

The issue is when the exception is thrown. (For example when i start to type the date in the TextFiled). Instead of appearing the decorator field to indicated an error in the input, the exception is not catch.

The exception appears in the console log (The error in the logs is at the end of the question) as it seems that nobody is catching it.

What i am missing? The exception in the converter should be catch within the updateStrategy and display the error, shouldn't it?

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.databinding 4 0 2017-08-18 15:16:27.816
>   !MESSAGE Invalid time Format
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid time Format
>       at com.lsespace.earthcare.tds.gui.util.databinding.conversion.StringToJavaTimeTagConverter.convert(StringToJavaTimeTagConverter.java:21)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.UpdateStrategy.convert(UpdateStrategy.java:715)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.UpdateValueStrategy.convert(UpdateValueStrategy.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.ValueBinding$3.run(ValueBinding.java:175)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm$1.run(Realm.java:149)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.safeRun(Realm.java:153)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.exec(Realm.java:171)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.ValueBinding.doUpdate(ValueBinding.java:158)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.ValueBinding.access$4(ValueBinding.java:147)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.ValueBinding$1.handleValueChange(ValueBinding.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.ChangeManager.fireEvent(ChangeManager.java:117)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.DecoratingObservableValue.fireValueChange(DecoratingObservableValue.java:61)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.DecoratingObservableValue.handleValueChange(DecoratingObservableValue.java:103)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.DecoratingObservableValue$1.handleValueChange(DecoratingObservableValue.java:76)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.ChangeManager.fireEvent(ChangeManager.java:117)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.AbstractObservableValue.fireValueChange(AbstractObservableValue.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.property.value.SimplePropertyObservableValue.notifyIfChanged(SimplePropertyObservableValue.java:126)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.property.value.SimplePropertyObservableValue.access$3(SimplePropertyObservableValue.java:118)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.property.value.SimplePropertyObservableValue$1$1.run(SimplePropertyObservableValue.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm$1.run(Realm.java:149)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.safeRun(Realm.java:153)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.exec(Realm.java:171)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.property.value.SimplePropertyObservableValue$1.handleEvent(SimplePropertyObservableValue.java:66)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.property.NativePropertyListener.fireChange(NativePropertyListener.java:69)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.internal.databinding.swt.WidgetListener.handleEvent(WidgetListener.java:56)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1084)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.wmCommandChild(Text.java:3117)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_COMMAND(Control.java:4939)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4794)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5115)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2446)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.callWindowProc(Text.java:262)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4889)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(Text.java:2704)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2552)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3814)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
>       at com.lsespace.earthcare.tds.gui.jface.actions.EditConfigAction.run(EditConfigAction.java:39)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:436)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$$Lambda$57/765702264.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:161)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)

Comment: What makes you think the exception should be displayed? UpdateStrategy does catch the exception but just logs the error. By the way this is nothing to do with e4.

Comment: For example what i have seem here : https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2009/06/15/galileo-emf-databinding-part-4/  Throwing an exception in the converter is used for the same purpose i want to use it. Also, how would you be able to notify the convertion error to the user?  Are there other methods?

Comment: After checking the eclipse source code it is clear that org.eclipse.core.databinding.ValueBinding.doUpdate(ValueBinding.java:158) should have catch the exception as the convert is called within a try and catch block there

Comment: @greg-449  ok, now i see what you meant. I will create my own UpdateStrategy so the exception is not catch by the UpdateStrategy but by the ValueBinding as i expected. There is already a bug open about it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495789

Comment: You should be using a validator to report invalid data.

Comment: Not very eficient when you are dealing with dates as string. I would have to have a validator to parse the string as the valid date format string and then re-parse it again to convert the string to a date/time class. Thus, it makes sense to do it all once only in the converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the implementation of the UpdateStrategy that I use so exceptions in the converter are treated like validation exceptions.

```
/**
 * This implementation of UpdateValueStrategy does not catch the exceptions thrown by the converter,
 * thus letting the normal mechanism of ValueBinding deal with the exception as it will do with a
 * validation exception.
 *
 */
public class AlternativeUpdateValueStrategy extends UpdateValueStrategy {

 public AlternativeUpdateValueStrategy() {
    this(UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_UPDATE);
 }

 public AlternativeUpdateValueStrategy(int updateStrategy) {
    super(updateStrategy);
 }

 @Override
 public Object convert(Object value) {
    if (converter != null) {
        return converter.convert(value);
    }
    return value;
 }

}
```